# How to get list of android emulators through terminal?

Tags: android, android-emulator, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I want to retrieve a list of android emulators from the terminal. How do I achieve this? I'm using ubuntu.

Answer (score 21):

Type this in command line:

```
emulator -list-avds
```

Answer (score 3):

go the android sdk path-> then go to the platform-tools -> type the command as
"adb devices"
you will be able to get the list of connected devices or emulators which are currently running.

Comment: "adb devices" helps me in retrieving a list of all the devices that are connected. But what if I dont know that I have an emulator 'em42'? I got the answer. You should look into 'root/.android/avd' folder. Thanks for trying to help. :)